# I18n Springboot de uma biblioteca externa

Tags: java, spring-boot

Senhores, em meu sistema tenho um componente externo que contem o bean messagesource configurado da seguinte maneira :

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("classpath:i18n/core/messages");
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return source;
}
```

No entanto  necessito que as mensagens de exceções sejam exibidas na aplicação que esta importando ele, algo que não está ocorrendo :

```
br.com.mv.liberty.editor3core.exception.vo.StudioException: group.length.max.description
```

Como devo configurar minha aplicação para exibir as mensagens desse componente embarcado ?

Answer (score 0):

Como o baseName está `source.setBasename("classpath:i18n/core/messages");`, você precisa colocar o arquivo de `messages.properties` dentro do seguinte diretório:

```
 src/main/resources/i18n/core/message.properties
```